# Train inactive class in classification AI problem

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm facing an issue. I want to classify data in n classes. But, I also want to say that, the answer is none of these n classes.

For example, my classes are : **HORSE**, **CAT**, **DOG**. So I will train with data related to **HORSE**, **CAT** and **DOG**.

But if I give my model something else, just like a car, I would like my model to tell that it is not HORSE or DOG or CAT. 
So maybe I have to train a model with these classes : **HORSE**, **CAT**, **DOG**, **OTHER** ?

But If I train **OTHER** class with data, how can I be sure that if I give it something new like a spacerocket, the prediction will be active for the **OTHER** class ?

In other words, I'm in trouble with inactive class. I don't want my model to give "the best prediction" beetween my desired classes, I also want it to tell me if it is none of them.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some answer, and it seems that there are 2 main solutions for this problem :

1. As I thought, I can train my classes and 1 more for the other cases. To be robust, I have to create data for this class that my model may have in input to cover as much as cases as possible !
2. Train n classifier : 1 binary classifier for 1 class. Each one have these outputs : Active / Not Active.

For each solution, I think it is necessary to create dataset for the "other cases", even in the second one to avoid uncontained prediction. In Solution 1, you can choose if you want 1 active class (softmax) or several active classes (sigmoid), in solution 2, it seems harder to control this behavior as each classifier is independent and several classes could be active.

[source](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/how-to-implement-an-unknown-class-in-nn-classification)